# Regex to remove certain strings from a comma separated strings

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

I have a string which looks like below

```
string = "NO PICK: hey there, hey you,NO PICK:hey there you, haha"
```

Now I want to remove any string that contains `NO PICK:` from the comma separated strings such that the end result looks like this

```
string = "hey you, haha"
```

I know how to remove the `NO PICK:` from the entire string itself by doing something like this

```
import re
string = string.replace("NO PICK:", "")
print(string)
```

But I do not know how to build a `regex` to remove entire substrings containing the match while keeping the other comma separated strings intact.

**Note:** I am using pandas to join values of certain columns that have these strings and remove `NO PICK:` from them.

Here is my below example

```
cc = [i for i in df.columns if i.startswith("Data")]
df[c] = df[cc].astype('unicode').apply(','.join, axis=1)
```

Here the value of `df[cc]` should not contain those strings that that `NO PICK:`

Comment: Split by comma, remove any element containing `NO PICK:` and join back.

Comment: You are not using a regex, and you do not need it. Use `', '.join([x for x in string.split(",") if "NO PICK:" not in x])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pandas, you may use

```
df[cc].astype(str).str.replace(r'NO PICK:[^,]*,*', '').str.strip()
```

The regex is `NO PICK:[^,]*,*`:

- `NO PICK:` - a literal text
- `[^,]*` - zero or more chars other than a comma
- `,*` - zero or more commas.

The `.str.strip()` will remove redudant leading/trailing whitespaces.

If you just work with strings, you may use

```
string = "NO PICK: hey there, hey you,NO PICK:hey there you, haha"
print( ', '.join([x.strip() for x in string.split(",") if "NO PICK:" not in x]).strip() )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/cUmqSx)

Notes:

- `string.split(",")` splits the string with commas
- `if "NO PICK:" not in x]` discards all items with `NO PICK:` in them
- `x.strip()` strips the leading/trailing  whitespace from the "valid" splits
- `', '.join(...).strip()` joins the "valid" items and remove any leading/trailing whitespace

Comment: Hi Wiktor! Actually I posted a very small example of what I am doing. I am actually using pandas to read from a csv where lot of columns have such values and I am trying to combine values of all such columns into one making sure `NO PICK: ` doesn't appear in the final joined values. Let me update my question.

Comment: @SouvikRay You should always post the real-life scenarios and add the relevant tags and details.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will remember this next time.

Comment: @SouvikRay Try `df[cc].astype(str).str.replace(r'NO PICK:[^,]*,*', '').str.strip()`

Answer (score 1):

you can split the string and the check for NO PICK, if NO PICK is not in the list
substring then append it into a list and finally join the list with ','

```
import re
value = "NO PICK: hey there, hey you,NO PICK:hey there you, haha"
value = value.split(',')
string = [v for v in value if not re.search('NO PICK', v)]
print(','.join(string))
```